# Using Retrofit 2.0 to extract information from a network API

Tags: java, android, retrofit, translate

I'm a newcomer in Java programming and in the past few days i've been experimenting with a basic English to Greek speech translation app purely to help me learn some (more advanced) concepts. Here is a [picture of the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzjIg.jpg).

So far I've gotten the speech recognition to work for both languages and I've decided to use [MyMemory's API](http://mymemory.translated.net/doc/spec.php)  as a REST API for translation. I'm using Retrofit 2.0.0-beta2 to turn the HTTP API into a Java interface.

At the moment I'm simply trying to extract the translation of a word/phrase from MyMemory and place it in a text field inside my application.

Currently, I have three classes in my project:

1. TranslateAPI (Interface)
2. TranslatedData
3. MainActivity

TranslateAPI

```
public interface TranslateAPI {
    @GET("get")
    void getTranslation(@Query("q") String request, Callback<TranslatedData> cb);
}
```

TranslatedData

```
public class TranslatedData {
    String translatedText;

    public String getTranslatedText(){
        return translatedText;
    }
}
```

MainActivity (Relevant Code)

```
        public void translate(String toTranslate){
        String request = "=" + toTranslate + "&langpair=" + langPair;
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://api.mymemory.translated.net/")
                .build();
        TranslateAPI service = retrofit.create(TranslateAPI.class);
        service.getTranslation(request, new Callback<TranslatedData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<TranslatedData> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                System.out.println("Success");
                //handle success
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Failure");
                //handle failure
            }
        });        
    }
```

A few questions arise here. First of all, the app crashes because of the translate() method and I can't undestand why (my debugging skills in android are still non-existent). Can anyone please help me figure out why?

Secondly, how exactly do i parse the response from the server?

Does my code have any other flaw that prevents the app from working/crashes it?

I apologize if my question is poor or straightforward, i'm still new to Android and i've found most tutorials about Retrofit vague and confusing due to the fact that half the guides are writen in Retrofit 1.x and the other half 2.0.

Comment: plug your phone into your computer. If you're using Android Studio, it should automatically open to the console (logcat interface) when you deploy the application to your device. If you're not, you can use adb logcat to manually capture that information from your device. That's a good place to start. Something that might be causing your app to crash (I'm not 100% sure), is network use on the main thread or not declaring that your app requires network access.

Comment: Hello Tyler, appreciate the early reply. I am asking for permission for network access on the manifest file. I'm quite condifent the problem is with the translate() method because if i comment out that method then the app runs fine without any problems. I feel like i'm one line away from the solution but i'm unsure where the problem lies exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrofit provides annotations to build proper calls, by the way, in this special case you need to build this kind of URI:

http://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=hola&langpair=ES|EN

The parameter value of `langpair` includes the character: **|** which need to be escaped (I've spend some time with that), that could be the reason of the crash.

You can easily fix it set that parameter as encoded in the signature of your Retrofit 2 API declaration:

```
@GET("/get")
Call<TranslatedData> getTranslation(
    @Query("q") String textToTranslate, 
    @Query(value = "langpair", encoded = true) 
String languagePair);
```

Then encode the parameter value:

```
mService.getTranslation(textToTranslate, URLEncoder.encode(fromLanguage + "|" + toLanguage))
    .enqueue(new Callback<TranslatedData>() {
```

Also you had some errors in your response entity, the object that contains the `translatedText` property is a JsonObject called `responseData`, you need to set the proper entities:

```
class TranslatedData {
    ResponseData responseData;
}

class ResponseData {
    String translatedText;
}
```

---

I post you the whole file of the `TranslateApi.java`, I've test it and works ;)

```
package com.example.alex.finalproject;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import retrofit.Call;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit.Response;
import retrofit.Retrofit;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.Query;

class TranslatedData {
    ResponseData responseData;
}

class ResponseData {
    String translatedText;
}

public class TranslateAPI {
    private static final String ENDPOINT = "http://api.mymemory.translated.net";
    public final static String SPANISH = "ES";
    public final static String ENGLISH = "EN";


    private final TranslateService mService;

    public interface TranslateService {
        @GET("/get")
        Call<TranslatedData> getTranslation(
            @Query("q") String textToTranslate,
            @Query(value = "langpair", encoded = true)
        String languagePair);
    }

    public TranslateAPI() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        mService = retrofit.create(TranslateService.class);
    }

    public void translate(final String textToTranslate, final String fromLanguage, final String toLanguage) {
        mService.getTranslation(textToTranslate, URLEncoder.encode(fromLanguage + "|" + toLanguage))
            .enqueue(new Callback<TranslatedData>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<TranslatedData> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    String output =
                        String.format("Translation of: %s, %s->%s = %s", textToTranslate,
                            fromLanguage, toLanguage, response.body().responseData.translatedText);

                    System.out.println("Result: " + output);
                }

                @Override public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    System.out.println("[DEBUG]" + " RestApi onFailure - " + "");
                }
            });
    }
}
```

You can call the translate method in this way:

```
translateAPI.translate("hola", TranslateAPI.SPANISH, TranslateAPI.ENGLISH);
```

My console result:

```
I/System.out(31427): Result: Translation of: hola, ES->EN = hello
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough mate. Thank you so much for your time, you really helped me there. :) It works perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 3):

On Android Studio, at the bottom, you have the **Android Monitor**, where you can find stacktraces with errors and more information, errors will be highlighted with red there.

[image: Android Monitor]

To parse a response from the server with Retrofit 2.0 you need to specify a converter. Example: if you would like to use Gson as your Entity converter first you have to add that dependency into your `build.gradle`file.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

Then you have to specify it into your Retrofit adapter:

```
 Retrofit marvelApiAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(END_POINT)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
    .client(client)
    .build();
```

If not you'll get a crash. Maybe the best suggestion would be that you should use Retrofit 1.9 by now, which is stable, the second version is in beta version at the moment of writing. On the other hand [in this link](https://t.co/7Ifkd3lJmn) you'll find a nice guide of how to migrate from the 1.9 version to the 2.0 version, in case that you are following 1.9 tutorials, which is probably :)

Comment: Thanks for your response Saulmm. I have included the Gson object now, thanks for pointing that out. Do i also need to create an OkHttpClient and call the .client() method in my project? At that point, the app still crashes even after i create the Gson object and call the .addConverterFactory(. . .) method.

Comment: Alexandros, I've just created a very simple working example of how Retrofit 2 works -> https://github.com/saulmm/Retrofit-2-basic-sample

Import it into android studio, see how it works, and then you could replace the endpoint, the callback type and your entity class. :)

Comment: You're a hero. Thanks so much man! :) I'll give it another attempt and let you know if I managed to make it work.

Comment: Hey Saulumm. Unfortunately after giving it another try this morning, i still can't get the program to work. Maybe it'll help if you have a look at my entire code?

I've imported the project on Github if you're still interested in helping. Sorry if i'm being a burden, I'm just very overwhelmed by this problem and I'm too stubborn to give up. I really appreciate your help so far. :)

This is the github link. https://github.com/AlexandrosParpas/TranslationDraft